# SFTP-based client to auto-open files from different folder

Tags: windows, ssh, notepad++, sftp, winscp

I am working on a programming project that has multiple text-based files (`.txt`, `.py`, `.sh`, etc.). The files are stored on a remote server (specifically AWS EC2). I can access them with WinSCP via SFTP and edit them with Notepad++. WinSCP saves them in a temporary folder and continuously checks for changes that are uploaded to the server.

However, the files on the server are located in different folders and every time I connect I have to open them all again by navigating to those directories. I would like to ask whether there is any SFTP client on Windows or any other way to open all of them at once. Since I do not add new files, it is OK if I can find a solution that saves the *session* of open files and reopens that session during next connection. Or, perhaps, since the parent folder of all of their folders is the same is there a method that recursively opens all files in subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinSCP function [Keep remote directory up to date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_keepuptodate).

Create a copy of the remote files in some local directory. Start WinSCP and have it monitor the local copies for changes. Use your favourite editor to edit the *local* files.